# Почему браузер игнорирует анимацию?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-animation

сейчас я разбираюсь с анимационными эффектами с помощью css и javascript и хочу реализовать алгоритм похожий на VueJs чтобы лучше понимать как это все работает и вот столкнулся с несколькими проблемами и вопросами.

1. Почему в обработчике события для btnShow если я не буду использовать таймер на 0 секунд, то у меня просто не сработает анимация, ведь алгоритм вроде правильный сначала ставлю класс enter, чтобы задать начальные стили, потом задаю enter-active - для изменения начальных стилей, потом сразу удаляю enter, и когда сработает событие transitionend уберу обработчик события на элемент.
   В теории все должно работать, но на практике получается все не так, анимация во все не работает, js вообще не ставит класс enter, я конечно догадываюсь, что это такая оптимизация браузера и что типа браузер видит добавление, а потом удаление класса и вообще его не ставит, но все равно я не понимаю как это работает и почему. Почему браузер не выполняет команды подряд, почему код ведет себя так непредсказуемо, что этому способствует?

   ```
   elem.style.display = 'inline-block';
   elem.classList.add('enter');
   elem.classList.add('enter-active');
   elem.classList.remove('enter');
   ```
2. Почему settimeout это исправляет?
3. Почему опять же если я чуть меняю алгоритм и здесь уже сразу после enter добавляю enter-active, то анимация тоже не сработает, браузеру именно надо чтоб я добавил сначала enter, а потом ставил интервал и только в нем уже добавлял новый класс и удалял старый. Почему так ? Как это вообще работает, уже голова кругом если честно))

   elem.style.display = 'inline-block';
       elem.classList.add('enter');
       elem.classList.add('enter-active'); 
       setTimeout(function() {
       elem.classList.remove('enter');
       }, 0);

   Заранее большое спасибо, если объясните как это все работает в браузере и почему надо делать именно так, чтоб в дальнейшем это не было сюрпризом для меня))

```js
var btnHide = document.querySelector('.hide');
var btnShow = document.querySelector('.show');
var elem = document.querySelector('.block');
btnHide.addEventListener('click', function () {
    elem.classList.add('leave-active');
    function handler() {
        elem.style.display = "none";
        elem.classList.remove('leave-active');
        elem.removeEventListener('transitionend', handler);
    }
    elem.addEventListener('transitionend', handler);
});

btnShow.addEventListener('click', function () {
    elem.style.display = 'inline-block';
    elem.classList.add('enter');
  //  elem.classList.add('enter-active'); ??
    setTimeout(function() {
        elem.classList.remove('enter');
        elem.classList.add('enter-active');
    }, 0);
    elem.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
        elem.classList.remove('enter-active');
    });
});
```

```css
.block {
    background: greenyellow;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px;
}

.leave-active {
    transition: opacity, 1s;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(200px);
}
.enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-200px)
}
.enter-active {
    transition: opacity 1s, transform 1s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class="btns">
        <button class="hide">Hide</button>
        <button class="show">Show</button>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Vitae nemo labore autem tempora.</p>
        <p>Tenetur earum ab suscipit unde?</p>
        <p>Labore eius accusantium ullam voluptatum.</p>
        <p>Necessitatibus similique mollitia cumque incidunt.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="some">
        <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList
>    `elem.classList.toggle( String [, Boolean])`
>    Если класс у элемента отсутствует - добавляет, иначе - убирает.
>    Когда вторым параметром передано false - удаляет указанный класс, а если true - добавляет.

---

### Пример раз

```js
var btnHide = document.querySelector('#hide');
var btnShow = document.querySelector('#show');
var elem = document.querySelector('.block');
// --
btnHide.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // это
  // elem.classList.remove('enter');
  // elem.classList.add('leave');
  // заменятся на это
  elem.classList.toggle("leave");
});
// --
btnShow.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // это
  // elem.classList.remove('leave');
  // elem.classList.add('enter');
  // заменятся на это
  elem.classList.toggle("leave");
});
// --
```

```css
.block {
  background: greenyellow;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 250px;
  /*показываем медленнее*/
  transition: height 4s, opacity 1s, transform 1s;

  /* это для наглядности - удалить
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px)
  */
}

.leave {
  /*прячем - быстрее*/
  transition: height 2s, opacity 1s, transform 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  transform: translateX(200px);
}


/* это для наглядности - удалить
.enter {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px)
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <button id="hide">Hide</button>
  <button id="show">Show</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Vitae nemo labore autem tempora.</p>
  <p>Tenetur earum ab suscipit unde?</p>
  <p>Labore eius accusantium ullam voluptatum.</p>
  <p>Necessitatibus similique mollitia cumque incidunt.</p>
</div>
<div class="some">
  <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

у этого примера есть недостаток - необходимо заранее знать высоту

```
.block {
  height: 250px;
}
```

эта проблема решается с помощью JS так

### Пример два

```js
var btnHide = document.querySelector('#hide');
var btnShow = document.querySelector('#show');
var elem = document.querySelector('.block');
// --
btnHide.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // это
  // elem.classList.remove('enter');
  // elem.classList.add('leave');
  // заменятся на это
  elem.classList.toggle("leave");
});
// --
btnShow.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // это
  // elem.classList.remove('leave');
  // elem.classList.add('enter');
  // заменятся на это
  elem.classList.toggle("leave");
});
// --
    let elStyle = getComputedStyle(elem);
    document.head.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
        <style>
        .block {
            background: greenyellow;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 15px;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: ${elStyle.height};
            /*показываем медленнее*/
            transition: height 4s, opacity 1s, transform 1s;
        }

        .leave {
            /*прячем - быстрее*/
            transition: height 2s, opacity 1s, transform 1s;
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
            transform: translateX(200px);
        }
        </style>
    `)
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <button id="hide">Hide</button>
  <button id="show">Show</button>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Vitae nemo labore autem tempora.</p>
  <p>Tenetur earum ab suscipit unde?</p>
  <p>Labore eius accusantium ullam voluptatum.</p>
  <p>Necessitatibus similique mollitia cumque incidunt.</p>
</div>
<div class="some">
  <p>Lorem, ipsum.</p>
</div>
```